# Problem with using javascript to insert <input> tags in html

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take text that is in an array (one word per value) and insert it into html. All the code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/r6wVq/3/.

Update:
My question is what am I doing wrong? It does not do anything which is weird.

Just for everybody who was wondering what this code is supposed to help me do is memorize long passages for school.

Comment: Thank you for crashing my browser!

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me. Also, what is your question?

Comment: You have a syntax error... you have to wrap the `<input>` element into single quotes: `extPrelim = '<input type="text"></input>'` If you then run the code, your browser crashes ;) In general, the code seems to be strange, e.g. you call `Math.floor()` without passing a value and `blanks` seems to be always empty, so the `for` loops will never run.

Comment: @Pekka exactly. sorry about that I meant to ask. I will update the question above.

Comment: Yeah, mine too, after @Felix's fix! A brand-new Chrome 5. I hope you have insurance! :)

Comment: brand-new chrome 8 doesn't crash :]

Comment: thats weird. Why would it crash the browser?

Comment: @Felix hmm... ok thanks, its probably because Im a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yEKPt/1/

What was wrong:

1. for iterator scope ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992254/problem-with-using-javascript-to-insert-input-tags-in-html/3992372#3992372))
2. This line (27) threw a syntax error:

   ```
   textPrelim = <input type="text"></input> //Needs to be quoted.
   ```

   Should be:

   ```
   textPrelim = '<input type="text"></input>'; //Quoted.
   ```
3. You reversed Math.random and Math.floor (lines 8, 14). (See: [`Math.Random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), [`Math.Floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor))

   ```
   var blank = Math.random(Math.floor() * (text.length / 2));
   ```

Check out my revised version. I think it accomplishes what you were looking for?

Comment: Good job! :)... @chromedude: I suggest to accept this as answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have an infinite loop, that's why the browser crashes:

```
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var currentText = text[i];
    for (i = 0; i<blanks.length; i++){}
}
```

The second loop always resets the counter variable `i` to `0`. If you have nested loops you have to use different variables. And use `var` to declare the variables as local, e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var currentText = text[i];
    for ( var j = 0; j<blanks.length; j++){
    }
}
```

Same for your most outer `for` loop!

---

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve with the code, but here are some comments:

```
var blankNum = Math.random(Math.floor() * (text.length / 2));
```

[`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) takes no parameter, but [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) does.

```
for (i = 0; i < blanks.length; i++) {
```

`blanks` is still empty at this point, so the loop will never run.

```
if (currentText==blanks[i]){
```

Are you sure that `blanks[i]` will contain text? The previous mentioned (never running) loop seems to add numbers to the array.

```
 textPrelim = <input type="text"></input>
```

You get a syntax error here, you must enclose the string into quotes.

Comment: thanks, I completely messed up on the `math.random(math.floor` part I meant for it to be the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

With addition to Felix's answer, try to check your code at http://www.jslint.com for syntax errors and undeclared (implicitly global) variables.